# Message body writer for ArrayList and my List<CustomType>, and MIME media type application/xml was not found?

Tags: java, xml, spring, jax-rs

I need some help with the following - First, here is the error I am getting :

```
SEVERE: A message body writer for Java class java.util.ArrayList, and Java type java.util.List<CustomType>, and MIME media type application/xml was not found
```

and here is the endpoint I have written :

```
@GET
@Path("/getListOfObjects")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
public Response getListOfObjects()
{
    List<CustomType> results = customTypeService.getListOfObjects();

    GenericEntity<List<CustomType>> genericList
    = new GenericEntity<List<CustomType>>(results){};

    return Response.ok(genericList).build();
}
```

Now, I will add that I actually had this error originally when I was trying to build the response with the initial list ("results") - but various other people had asked a similar question on here, and were all told make it a generic entity in the way I did above... However, it seems to have had no effect for me.

Anyone here have some input for me?

Comment: Could you include how the `CustomType` is defined?

Comment: Custom type is just an object with two properties - One which is a long, and is used for an id, and the other, which is the name on record.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error normally occurs when the custom type is not properly annotated using the JAXB annotations to allow XML marshalling.

Try adding `@XmlRootElement` to the class declaration along with binding the member fields:

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlRootElement
public class CustomType {
   long id;
   String name;

   ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks!! That fixed it immediately - What sucks is that I knew this already! I thought I had it in my class already! :(

Answer (score 0):

Can you try `Response.ok().entity(genericList).build()`, as:

```
@GET
@Path("/getListOfObjects")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
public Response getListOfObjects(){
        List<CustomType> results = customTypeService.getListOfObjects();
        GenericEntity<List<CustomType>> genericList= new GenericEntity<List<CustomType>>(results){};
        return Response.ok().entity(genericList).build();
}
```